# Showing multiple GPS devices at the same time in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, multiple

Is it possible to show multiple live GPS devices at the same time in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research on the issue?

Comment: By "show" I presume you mean display the location, together with a unique id. So, you will need to investigate methods to capture the identity and location of multiple GPS receivers. Over to you..